How to resolve JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ error in Android?
Here is the relevant part of my Retrofit setup:
package com.example.android2024.axios;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class api {
    private static String token;

    public static String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public static void setToken(String token) {
        api.token = token;
    }

    public static <T> T getService(Class<T> serviceClass){
        // 请求响应拦截器
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://172.20.4.47:8080/")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to set the Gson instance to lenient mode in my Retrofit setup by doing the following:
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
   
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
       .build();

Despite setting the Gson instance to lenient mode, the app still throws the same error:
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

setLenient() on Gson allows for more relaxed parsing of JSON data types, but it doesn't directly affect how Retrofit handles malformed JSON structures. The error suggests the problem lies with the overall structure of the JSON response, not data type issues. If you can share the specific error message or a snippet of the malformed JSON, I might be able to provide more specific guidance.

Commands [Hash = -473957050, id=11, tl=1.0, th=1.0, sun=1.0, day=1, all1=1, light2=1, light1=1, time=1, st=1, serialVersionUID=1]

my suggestion is to check for the model the model is not properly mapped

It seems like your result is in form of string not JSON. For string response, we use ScalarsConverterFactory in Retrofit Builder.
Step # 1
Add Dependency
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.11.0") // for kotlin
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.11.0' // for groovy

Remove GsonConverterFactory and add ScalarsConverterFactory as following
public static <T> T getService(Class<T> serviceClass){
    // 请求响应拦截器
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://172.20.4.47:8080/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())  // <- Change
            .build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}


Oh, indeed, that's right. On the server side, the return type is String. I now know how to change it. Thank you very much for your help.

you are welcome, Can you accept my answer, as your problem got solved, so others can also get benefits by your answer acceptance

Of course, I apologize for my tardiness.

No problem, & thanks
